# file based logging in .net 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, logging

since .NET 7 does not provide file based logging out of the box . what is a good third party library for file based logging in .net7.

I have looked into serilog but it does not allow to add as package

Comment: what do you mean about ` serilog does not allow to add as package` ? You can't use nuget to add it? `serilog` and  `nlog` are all the recommended log library